# How should I list Freelance products in my resume

Tags: resume

I'm a software developer engineer, I have 2 years experience in a company, in the same time I work like a freelancer, I make many products(softwares) and now I want to list them in my resume, my questions is :

- Is it good idea to list freelance product in the resume
- What is the good way to list them
- About the time generally we use the month and the year so if I list them it can be a conflict between my professional job and freelance job, so how can I list them, should I list them in another part or with my professional products, or how?

Comment: do you own the products?

Comment: yes @Kilisi i do

Comment: Who do you work for? Yourself? Usually if you have a professional job, the company owns the products.

Comment: ahh you mean the company products of course i don't own them products i thought you meant freelance products @Kilisi

Comment: Keep in mind there is also a SE site for Freelancers. I think this question is  suitable for here though. https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I see thank you @DCON i will wait for the moderators what should decide if that, then they can move it there :)

Comment: the simple answer is **yes, of course, put them in your CV.**  Couldn't be simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I would list the freelance job in your work experience as a concurrent position. (It is not uncommon for people who work projects/part-time jobs to have multiple positions at the same time.) And then describe each project within that space.

So let's say you stared freelancing in April 2015. I'd add 04/2015 - present: Freelance software developer.

1. Project x: your role in the project. skills and technologies used.
2. Project y: your role in the project. skills and technologies used.

This is could be different in your area though, so it might help if you tell us where you are from. This answer was written with a Dutch/European point of reference.

Comment: a lot of companies claim ownership of anything you develop while working for them, check the contract first.

Comment: thank you @Arnold Wiersma this is good point in reality i start freelance before professional job so should i put the freelance part before or after?

Comment: @Kilisi I fail to see how ownership would be relevant to a listing of work experience.  Regardless of who owns the product you can tell potential employers what your skills are.

Comment: @YCF_L I would put them in reverse chronological order. So start with your most recent job.

Comment: @ArnoldWiersma you outline your experience and proven skillset, not the products unless you own them or have permission.

Comment: @Kilisi That was what I meant, I have changed 'description' to "your role in the project' to make it more clear. I would still group it on a per project basis because that shows which skills are used often and adds context.